# ignore punctuation when checking if a word is an English word

Tags: python, enchant

I am looking for the best way to correct potential misspells for words in a string, without taking the punctuation into account. I do not want to strip it before doing that evaluation as this would alter the final edited string. My current approach uses py-enchant (.check() method) after having splitted the string on whitespaces, but this will not ignore punctuation.

`misspelled_string = 'This is a (tesl strung.'`

Desired output :

`corrected_string = 'This is a (test string.'`

Comment: _I do not want to strip it before doing that evaluation as this would alter the final edited string._ How come that isn't an issue with splitting?

Answer (score 0):

Try splitting by anything that is not a letter, with `re`:

```py
import re
misspelled_string = 'This is a (tesl strung.'

res=re.split(r"[^\w]+", misspelled_string)
```

Output:

```py
>>> res
['This', 'is', 'a', 'tesl', 'strung', '']
```